# ActionBarCompat change item icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, compatibility, android-actionbar-compat

I am working on an application for API 7+ that implements ActionbarCompat.

Currently I have an activity with a "favourite" icon on the ActionBar and I am trying to find a way to toggle the graphic between favourite and not favourite.

All my efforts with playing around in onCreateOptionsMenu, onPrepareOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected have failed, it appears the icon can only be changed at the time of creation and not while the activity is already running.

Has anybody come across a way to change one of these ActionBarCompat item icons at run time while the activity is visible using ActionBarCompat and still maintain compatability with the native ActionBars on APIs 11+?

Comment: [supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#supportInvalidateOptionsMenu%28%29) looks like it might help in this case.

Comment: ^ This is the correct answer. A combination of this and switching your icon graphic at the correct time causes it to update.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement some basic logic in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` that checks whether the item is favourited or not and changes the icon based on that logic.

In your `setFavourite()` method, you'll need:

```
setFavourite() {
    ....
    if (changedFavourite)
       invalidateOptionsMenu()
```

See documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu()

That should force ABS to redraw.

Comment: Sorry, but that page on the developer blog clearly states that invalidateOptionsMenu() was implemented in API 11, and my question clearly states that I need it to run on APIs 7+. I had thought of this, but it's obviously a no go, for the above reasons.

Comment: ActionBarSherlock implements invalidateOptionsMenu() for API levels below 11. Try it and see.

Comment: ActionBarSherlock isn't an option I'm afraid, but I'll have a look at the source and see how they implement it. I read elsewhere it only pulled the API level requirement down to 10.

Comment: Aah, sorry. Read ActionBarCompat as ActionBarSherlock. ABS is awesome, I highly recommend it. It implements everything as far back as 2.x (so API level 7 I believe) and has 1:1 compatibility with all methods in the standard actionbar.

Comment: I'm afraid that because it's a commercial product I'm restricted in what I can use, for various reasons, and so ABS isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @mobinvent's comment I found that the following gives pre HoneyComb devices utlising ActionBarCompat the options menu lifecycle sequencing as per invalidateOptionsMenu() on HoneyComb and above.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) invalidateOptionsMenu();
else {
    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    openOptionsMenu();
    closeOptionsMenu();
}
```

Note the hacky requirement to open the options menu and close it. In my particular instance I call this from onActivityResult which at this stage does not appear to introduce any ugly menu flicker.

Good riddance to pre ActionBar OS / devices!